# Templates for forms, tabs etc? - Patterntap alternatives

Tags: design, forms, website-design

I used to find http://www.patterntap.com quite useful to get inspiration to design [forms](http://patterntap.com/tags/type/forms?platform%5B0%5D=5&sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&page=9), tabs, and other web elements etc.

Unfortunately after the [ZURB acquisition of Patterntap](http://www.zurb.com/article/1004/weve-acquired-pattern-tap) now they enforce you to sign in with your Twitter account in order to simply view larger images of patterns provided by the crowd. So in some way it's not free anymore.

Do you know of **alternatives to patterntap** that are free and you are not obliged to sign in?

Comment: Why -1? Don't you think places to get inspiration for front end design are useful and related to a "Pro Webmaster"?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Marco that's a pretty nice site. There are a few other sites like it. If you simply google "sites similar to http://patterntap.com/" you will see some listings one of them is below.

http://www.similarsitesearch.com/alternatives-to/patterntap.com

Comment: I did Googled before posting the question, but I could not find anything of interesting. Even the link you suggested list sites that do not seem to be at the same level of patterntap (see: http://ui-patterns.com/, http://patternry.com/)

Comment: @MarcoDemaio you asked for alternatives to patterntap I searched and gave you some alternatives.

Comment: Infact I was the one who gave you +1, I justed wanted to point out that I don't post a question here w/o Googling before.